# How to improve the LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

This is what i got:

```
int? productID = (ClientProduct != null ? (int?)ClientProduct.ProductID : null);

result = (from po in ((Chase_Media_Pro_Entity_Model)this.NavigationItem.ObjectContext).raPurchaseOrder_List
                  where po.ClientID == Client.CustomerID
                        && ((object.Equals(po.ClientProductID, productID)) || (po.ClientProductID == (productID ?? po.ClientProductID)))
                        && (po.Is_Active == (isActive ?? po.Is_Active))
                        && (po.IsApproved == (isApproved ?? po.IsApproved))
                  orderby po.Is_Active descending, po.IsApproved ascending
                  select po);
```

Is there a way to improve this line:

```
&& ((object.Equals(po.ClientProductID, productID)) || (po.ClientProductID == (productID ?? po.ClientProductID)))
```

This was the only way i could get the right results.

Comment: What's the type of `ClientProduct.ProductID`? Your code looks really weird.

Comment: @Danny: int. What looks weird to you? It's just handling NULL values.

Comment: So why are you using `object.Equals` to compare two integers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
&& ((productID.HasValue && po.ClientProductID.HasValue) ? po.ClientProductID.Value = productID.Value : true)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
&& (!productID.HasValue || (productID == po.ClientProductID))
```